# Does Twilio allow people to send a text message to a twilio account free of charge?

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, twilio-php

I was wondering if its possible to allow people to text to a twilio number without charging them sms charges by their carrier? So, for each text message that is sent to a twilio phone number, I will cover the cost. Basically, free or charge text messaging for users to a specific twilio number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

We support [incoming SMS messages on toll free numbers](https://www.twilio.com/sms/toll-free) in certain countries, so yes!

I recommend opening up the advanced search in the [phone number console](https://www.twilio.com/console/phone-numbers/search) and checking the boxes for toll free and SMS.

Comment: interesting. So, you can only use 1+800 as toll free numbers? No local numbers starting with such as 917, 646 etc....

Comment: That's correct, any other numbers are regular local numbers and people who send SMS messages to them will incur the normal costs.